# Can I include jsp as an innerHml in a jsp from javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jsp, innerhtml

Including an external jsp page as an innerHtml from a javascript function

Answer (score 2):

Yes. By the time it gets to the client (which is where the `innerHTML` is), a JSP page just looks like any other page loaded from the server. You have to load it with Ajax (using `XMLHttpRequest` [MSDN link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms535874%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) [MDC link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/xmlhttprequest)), which will give you the markup of the page, and then you assign it to the `innerHTML` property.